# Consuming web api with RestSharp basic authentication return null

Tags: http, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication, restsharp

I am trying to consume an endpoint with RestSharp with Basic authentication.
I followed the instructions on the documentation https://restsharp.dev/getting-started/getting-started.html
The request was successful but I think the request body was malformed.

How can I get this to work

```
  internal BalanceInquiryResponse BalanceInquiryRest(BalanceInquiryRequest BalanceInquiryRequest, Settings Settings)
        {
          // BalanceInquiryResponse BalanceInquiryResponse = new BalanceInquiryResponse();
            
            var client = new RestClient(Settings.BaseUrl + "All/Inquiry");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(Settings.Username, Settings.Password);
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddJsonBody(new
            {
                Acc = BalanceInquiryRequest.Acc
            });

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            IRestResponse<BalanceInquiryResponse> res = client.Execute<BalanceInquiryResponse>(request);
                        
            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                BalanceInquiryResponse = new BalanceInquiryResponse
                {
                    responseInquiry = res.Data.responseInquiry,
                    ResponseDescription = res.Data.ResponseDescription,
                    ResponseMessage = res.Data.ResponseMessage
                };
                return BalanceInquiryResponse;
            }
            else
            {
                BalanceInquiryResponse = new BalanceInquiryResponse
                {               
                    ResponseDescription = responseses.ErrorMessage,             
                };
                return BalanceInquiryResponse;
            }
        }
```

This is my response body

```
{
  "responseMessage": "Successful",
  "responseDescription": "Request Successful",
  "responseInquiry": null
}
```

When I tried with postman I got

```
{
    "ResponseMessage": "Successful",
    "ResponseDescription": "Request Successful",
    "response": {
        "AvalBal": 586324.42,
        "ReverAmt": 0,
        "AccCurrency": "US "
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your return/response http status code?

Comment: I got 200 response in my swagger UI

Comment: If you got a 200 (and you got a "hint" of  "responseMessage": "Successful",).......then technically, it is "working".  You need to verify with the server-side if anything happened with your POST data.  If responseInquiry is null, then that can be "normal".  Does the rest-service provide documenation on expected inputs/outputs (requests/resposes).

Comment: I have updated my question to see the response I got from postman

Comment: Ok, now i see the dilemma....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IRestResponse<BalanceInquiryResponse> res = client.Execute<BalanceInquiryResponse>(request);
```

So there is a specific reason...you are putting BalanceInquiryResponse in the generic IRestResponse above.

With the above call, this should automatically hydrate the BalanceInquiryResponse object, and you shouldn't need to hand map.

Aka, you should ~not~ need this below code:

```
            BalanceInquiryResponse = new BalanceInquiryResponse
            {
                responseInquiry = res.Data.responseInquiry,
                ResponseDescription = res.Data.ResponseDescription,
                ResponseMessage = res.Data.ResponseMessage
            };
```

I think your issue is that your POCO object (BalanceInquiryResponse) should perfectly match the "structure" of the JSON.

Change your BalanceInquiryResponse to PERFECTLY match the json "properties".

and recognize you have a nested object.

I think it it would be:

```
public class ResponsePoco    {
    public double AvalBal { get; set; } 
    public int ReverAmt { get; set; } 
    public string AccCurrency { get; set; } 
}

public class BalanceInquiryResponse{
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; } 
    public string ResponseDescription { get; set; } 
    public ResponsePoco response { get; set; } 
}
```

Pay attention the to "ResponsePoco response"..note the variable name is LOWERCASE .. because...the json has a lowercase "response" in it.
I have called the (child) object "ResponsePoco" to highlight the difference between the object name and the variable name.

If you cannot "perfectly" match the Poco properties. you can use attributes to "massage" the discrepencies.  As seen here:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

```
public class Videogame
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("release_date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I made changes to the response object